# Sequence issue with nested foreach loop php

Tags: php, foreach

I have two array. array one and array two. I want to merge these array into single array with key. My output result is valid but sequence is not correct.

```
Array one
    Array
    (
     [0] => test-685f1e7bc357187e449479d627100102
     [1] => test-685f1e7bc357187e449479d627d29390
    )
Array two
    Array
    (
    [0] => DF955298-A664-4FA7-9586-FCD4CF977777
    [1] => DF955298-A664-4FA7-9586-FCD4CF988888
    )

Expected Result
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => test-685f1e7bc357187e449479d627100102
                [uuid] => DF955298-A664-4FA7-9586-FCD4CF977777
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [key] => test-685f1e7bc357187e449479d627d29390
                [uuid] => DF955298-A664-4FA7-9586-FCD4CF988888
            )
    )
```

My code is for that result is mentioned below:

```
$record = array();
foreach ($keys_array as $key => $all_key) {
    foreach ($uuid_array as $uuid_key => $all_uuid) {
        $record[$key]['key'] = $all_key;
        $record[$uuid_key]['uuid'] = $all_uuid;
    }
}
```

My output sequence is not valid. Where is the problem

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => test-685f1e7bc357187e449479d627100102
                [uuid] => DF955298-A664-4FA7-9586-FCD4CF977777
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [uuid] => test-685f1e7bc357187e449479d627d29390
                [key] => DF955298-A664-4FA7-9586-FCD4CF988888
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
$record = array();
foreach ($keys_array as $key => $all_key) {
    $record[] = [
        'key' => $all_key,
        // get value under the same key from `$uuid_array`
        'uuid' => $uuid_array[$key],
    ];
}
```